# Adding javascript component into angular app

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm having a javascript components that is distributed as `.js` file and `.css` file. In `.js` file the component is added to `window`

window.Component = { ... }

the component should be added to page with the following code `Component.init('#componentHolderId', config);`

I need to use my component in an Angular app (using Angular 11 if that matters).

Here are my questions.

1. Where is the best place in angular app to put `.js` file? Maybe it's somehow possible to add it to lazy-loaded module (as component needs to be used in a lazy-loaded module)?
2. Is there a way to add css to project other that adding it to `styles` array in `angular.json`? My concern here is that this way will slow-up application start-up.

Comment: Can’t you just add it inside index.html..? Or if you need to add it conditionally (from a lazy module?) you could simply do some DOM manipulation inside the lazy module to add a script tag to the header..?

Comment: adding component conditionally is much more preferable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your `.js` file in the Scripts array of `angular.json`. so that it will be loaded.

Or you can add the `.js` inside the script tag inside body tag of index.html. (Sometimes it won't work because the some dom elaments are not present when loading index.html).

If you are using `SCSS` or any other `CSS` preprocessors, you can import your `CSS` files in your styles file.